# RecyclerView and CradView in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-recyclerview, android-cardview

I want to development an app that contains the following images.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UEmgn.png)

and I don't know how to do that with CardView

How to create a CardView that can be added like the image?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Simply add an image view inside a card view

```xml
<CardView
   android:width="wrap_content"
   android:height="wrap_content"
   app:cardElevation="2dp"> 
  <ImageView
     android:width="300dp"
     android:height="300dp"
     src="yourImgFile" />
</CardView>
```

And the image reference you provided, you can nest this code in another CardView element containing a Linear Layout with horizontal orientation i.e

```xml
<CardView
   android:width="match_parent"
   android:height="wrap_content"
   app:cardElevation="2dp"> 
  <LinearLayout
     android:width="match_parent"
     android:height="wrap_content"
     android:orientation="horizontal">

<CardView
   android:width="wrap_content"
   android:height="wrap_content"
   app:cardElevation="2dp"> 
  <ImageView
     android:width="300dp"
     android:height="300dp"
     src="yourImgFile" />
</CardView>


<CardView
   android:width="wrap_content"
   android:height="wrap_content"
   app:cardElevation="2dp"> 
  <ImageView
     android:width="300dp"
     android:height="300dp"
     src="yourImgFile" />
</CardView>


<CardView
   android:width="wrap_content"
   android:height="wrap_content"
   app:cardElevation="2dp"> 
  <ImageView
     android:width="300dp"
     android:height="300dp"
     src="yourImgFile" />
</CardView>


  </LinearLayout>
</CardView>
```